# How quadratic equation formed?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Where does a quadratic equation come from? We often use $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, but how is it formed? Is there any real life problem which can be converted into an equation like this and solved?

Comment: Yes, there is. In electrical engineering turn these kinds of equations op a lot. When dealing with resistor networks.

Comment: https://plus.maths.org/content/101-uses-quadratic-equation, https://plus.maths.org/content/101-uses-quadratic-equation-part-ii

Comment: Quadratic equations were first (as far as we know)  solved by Babylonians in the XVIIIth century B.C., for land survey problems – naturally not with our modern notations (dating back to Vieta at the end of the 16th century).

Comment: A projectile is launched from a known height above the ground, at a known speed, and at a known angle above horizontal; when and where will it hit the ground? This question is important for an outfielder who wants to throw out a runner, for a cannoneer of a castle on a cliff who wants to stop the approach of a pirate ship, and for me when I want to water my lawn without soaking nearby friends. Although these people often work by instinct or by trial-and-error, the exact answer to the question is obtained by solving a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

Real life Example is product of two consecutive natural no.is $6$
$$x(x+1)=6$$
$$x^2-x-6=0$$